# Access query returns a different result when read from Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have a query in an ACCDB that works fine in Access.
I can successfully copy/paste its data to Excel.

However, from Excel, if I try to insert a Pivot Table using External Data Source, pointing to the very same query, then some numeric fields have weird formatting and some *calculated* numeric columns (formula in the query) have their value divided by 100 compared to the source.
Never seen that behaviour. Any suggestion ?
The whole MS-Office setup is in 2010.
What I have already done in the source query (without visible improvement):

- used CCur() to make sure the figures are in a coherent data type
- set the Format property of those culprit columns to "Standard"

The behaviour is exactly the same on other PCs in the same bank.

Comment: Sounds like a decimal separator issue where dot becomes comma or vice-versa.

Or Percent formatted decimals that are read as decimals, not integer percent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the problem which was due to 2 different bugs, probably in JetOLEDB.

1. **`Like` is not handled properly by Excel**
   The query contained some formulae using `Like`:
   `iif(someField Like "XX*";0;anotherField)`.
   Changing this to `iif(Left(somefield;2) = "XX";0;anotherField)` solved calculation differences between Excel but and Access.
2. **Reference to another calculated column is handled differently**
   Say you have 2 query columns:
   `Rate: i.Rate *100`          (i is a table alias)
   `Amount: Rate*Price`
   Access calculates `Amount` using the `Rate` calculated column, while Excel uses the `Rate` field from table i.Therefore I had to change the `Amount` expression to:
   `Rate: i.Rate *100`
   `Amount: i.Rate *100*Price`
   since Excel does not seem to make always use `Rate` from the table (`i.Rate`).

Answer (score 0):

Use the query in Access to first **Make Table** in Access then import the table to excel.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).